# Bluetooth BNEP takes a long time to load on boot Debian

Tags: boot, bluetooth, dmesg

My system takes a long time to boot and looking at dmesg output I found an entry with BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3 that takes around 27 seconds to load.

Does anyone have a clue on how to speed it up or to disable it?

[**Here**](http://pastebin.com/vfgN7aZ7) is what my dmesg output looks like (Bluetooth isse is on line 844)

**EDIT:**
Output of systemd-analyze blame as GAD3R suggested:

```
  1m 31.246s openvas-manager.service
      8.827s networking.service
      7.455s dev-sda9.device
      5.675s accounts-daemon.service
      4.958s arpwatch.service
      4.467s redis-server.service
```

Looking at the output I realized that the problem was with openvas-manager which was probably delaynig the rest of processes and thus the issue was unrelated to the bluetooth service and after removing openvas-service boot time is now back to normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `mask` the service to make it imossible to start, using the following command:

```
systemctl mask unit
```

To get the exact bluetooth service , run `systemd-analyze blame` and replace it

**Edit**

The `openvas-manager` take `1m 31.246s`, the right command will be:

```
systemctl mask openvas-manager.service
```

If you need to re-enable it you can `unmask` , `enable` and `start` the service.