# Xubuntu slow startup/boot time

Tags: boot, xubuntu, dmesg

I have a Xubuntu desktop machine with an i3-7100, a NVME-system-drive and 6-hdd ZFS filesystem for multimedia storage (mainly running Desktop-Kodi) which takes longer than i expected to boot. When the system is running everything works fine. I tried closing in on the delay, but so far I couldn't really figure it out.
I already looked at a different thread ([Bluetooth BNEP takes a long time to load on boot Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289951/bluetooth-bnep-takes-a-long-time-to-load-on-boot-debian)) but the solution to diable the first item on the "blame list" (see below) would mean to disable network manager if I'm correct)

The biggest jump in load time from the dmesg ([full output](https://pastebin.com/sK80RXiu)) is at line 935/936:

```
[   13.355382] audit: type=1400 audit(1609884869.161:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1800 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   97.839886] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
```

systemd-analyze time gives:

```
Startup finished in 7.589s (kernel) + 3min 440ms (userspace) = 3min 8.029s
```

and systemd-analyze blame ([full output](https://pastebin.com/xJKMETnn)) shows:

```
30.570s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
 3.812s zfs-import-cache.service
 1.329s snap-irfanview-28.mount
```

as first three entries.

Is this a problem with the bluetooth device (if i understand the dmesg correctly a delay of 84s - if so, why isn't it shown in the "blame" list on top)?
Or is my network configuration bad? Or is the ZFS filesystem a cause for the slowdown?

I am not that experienced in linux, but I can manage to work in the console or follow hints.

Any help or tip is apprechiated :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to disable bluetooth without disabling NM. Please see the below article explaining how-to, it may also be good to see if there are any other drivers for your bluetooth device to install.

https://support.qacafe.com/knowledge-base/how-do-i-prevent-network-manager-from-controlling-an-interface/#configure-network-manager-to-ignore-test-interfaces

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I started the article and [nmcli dev status] gives the connected wifi device, 2 lan devices and the loopback, I found no connection to the bluetooth device. Additionally I tried deactivating bluetooth with  [systemctl mask bluetooth.service]. After reboot I got nearly the same times just without the bluetooth calls ... it seems to be a bad network configuration. I'll try to test and disable the different network devices and go over my configuration.